# How can I change slash (/) to hyphen in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have only using php and mysql in my website. I faced problem GET URL change slash to hyphen but not get data.

This is my .htaccess file code

```
RewriteRule ^list/(.*)/(.*)/$ /list.php?name=$1&date=$2
```

When I browsing my url like this `websitename/list/jhon/july-8-2023/` that's good and get data.

But I need changed 3rd slash (`jhon` after `/`)  to hyphen when I browsing this url data not showing

```
websitename/list/jhon-july-8-2023/
```

I try this, but not work

```
RewriteRule ^list/(.*)-(.*)/$ /list.php?name=$1&date=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `.*` means any character 0 or more times `(.*)-(.*)$` will cause the new URL to combine the capture groups resulting in `name = jhon-july-8` and `date = 2023`, because the pattern greedily adds all of the characters to the first capture group until the last `-123abcd#%|_/` at the end `$`.

To match the new URL format of `websitename/list/jhon-july-8-2023/`, the hyphens would need to be accounted for, in order to separate the `name` and `date` values into two regex capture groups.

Use one of the options below, based on your desired results.
Demonstration of the Regex patterns: https://3v4l.org/3qHUa

**Option 1: Simple Replacement**
This pattern works similarly to your original `(.*)/(.*)` but may result in false positive matches, since it doesn't account for the date format `abcd-1-1234` correctly and would be free to match `123-123-abc-abc-abc-abc` as an example.

```
RewriteRule ^list/(\w+)-(.*)/$ /list.php?name=$1&date=$2
```

- `^list/` begins with the word `list` followed by a forward-slash character
- `\w+` matches at least 1 or more alphanumeric characters or underscores
- `.*` matches any character 0 or more times
- `/$` requires the forward-slash character at the end

**Option 2: Explicit Rule**
This pattern will help reduce false positive matches by only accepting values of: `abcd-abcd-1-1234` or `abcd-abcd-12-1234`, with or without the `/` at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^list/([a-z]+)-([a-z]+-\d{1,2}-\d{4})/?$ /list.php?name=$1&date=$2
```

- `^list/` begins with the word `list` followed by a forward-slash character
- `[a-z]+` matches at least 1 or more lowercase alphabetic characters

  - to match upper and lower case use `[a-zA-Z]+`
- `\d{1,2}` matches at least 1 and at most 2 number characters
- `\d{4}` matches exactly 4 number characters
- `/?$` permits the forward-slash character as optional at the end

**Option 3: Lenient Explicit Rule**
This pattern will allow either a hyphen `-` or a `/` forward-slash to work with either URL format of `websitename/list/jhon-july-8-2023/` or `websitename/list/jhon/july-8-2023/`, and allow for letter and/or number combinations in the name and month of the date portions of the capture groups. Such as: `123_AbC/123_AbC-12-1234` or `123_AbC-123_AbC-12-1234`

```
^list/(\w+)[\-/](\w+-\d{1,2}-\d{4})/?$ /list.php?name=$1&date=$2
```

- `^list/` begins with the word `list` followed by a forward-slash character
- `\w+` matches at least 1 or more alphanumeric characters or underscores
- `[\-/]` matches one hyphen or forward-slash
- `\d{1,2}` matches at least 1 and at most 2 number characters
- `\d{4}` matches exactly 4 number characters
- `/?$` permits the forward-slash character as optional at the end

Comment: No worries I got it solved with another rule Thanks!